# Partial with Multiple Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, renderpartial

I am new to rails and need some guidance. I am sure I am misunderstanding something obvious.

I would like the user name of the person who leaves a comment to show on the view page. I have a partial that goes through the collection of comments for the particular object for example a school. I can't figure out how to pass that user variable into the partial so that I can display the login name for the comment. My Comments model is polymorphic and I am pretty sure that is making this more complex.

Here are the models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
has_many :comments, :through => :schools

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :installation
belongs_to :neighborhood
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users, :through => :schools
```

School's controller:

```
def show
  @installation = Installation.find(params[:installation_id])
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @neighborhood = @school.neighborhood
  @comment = @school.comments
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @school }
  end
end
```

The comment partial:

```
<div class="box-one">
<img src="/images/comment_top.png" alt="" />
<div class="inside">
    <p><span class="stars"><%= display_stars(comment.stars) %></span><br />
<%= comment.content %></p>  
</div>
<img src="/images/comment_bottom.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

The school view:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/comment", :collection => @comment %>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you can get to the `User` who made the comment from the `Comment` itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think your models might have some issues, but you pass parameters to partials using `locals`.

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/comment", :locals => { :user => your_user } %>
```

Then inside of the partial you have access to the user variable.

```
<p><span class="stars"><%= display_stars(comment.stars) %></span><br />
<%= comment.content %><br />
by <%= user %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

for example from me

```
def show 
@school = School.find_by_id_and_user_id(params[:id],
params[:user_id],:include => [:user, [:comments => :user]])
end
```

---

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  has_many :comments

  def after_save
   self.user.update_attribute(:last_activity, "bla bla bla")
   self.user.update_attribute(:last_activity_at, Time.now)
  end
end

 class User
   has_many :school or has_one
   has_many :comments
 end
```

---

```
<div class="box-one">
<img src="/images/comment_top.png" alt="" />
<div class="inside">
        <% @schools.comments.each do |comment| -%>
        <%= comment.created_at.to_s(:short) %>  
        <p><span class="stars"><%= <%= comment.user.stars %> said: ## or<%= comment.user.username %> said:##</p> %></span><br />
<%= comment.content %></p>  

</div>
<img src="/images/comment_bottom.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/comment"%>
```